# Navigate to any step in a Bootstrap step-wizard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my JSFiddle : [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/inchrvndr/8uwn0ph0/)

On click of "Save & Continue", the step navigates to the next step of the wizard.

How do I navigate to any step on click of a specific step? (instead of the step-by-step sequence that already exists)

```
  $('.f1 .btn-next').on('click', function() {
    var parent_fieldset = $(this).parents('fieldset');
    var next_step = true;
    // navigation steps / progress steps
    var current_active_step = $(this).parents('.f1').find('.f1-step.active');
    var progress_line = $(this).parents('.f1').find('.f1-progress-line');

    // fields validation
    parent_fieldset.find('input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea').each(function() {
        if( $(this).val() == "" ) {
            $(this).addClass('input-error');
            next_step = true;
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass('input-error');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:- Buttons added to jump to specific steps. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nidhinchandran/8uwn0ph0/7/)

EDIT:- I modified your fiddle [check this](https://jsfiddle.net/nidhinchandran/8uwn0ph0/6/)

Try this [JsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nidhinchandran/8uwn0ph0/2/) 
I modified the html slightly to connect steps div and corresponding fieldset by adding a data-step parameter to both. After the modification the below function will allow you to jump between steps by clicking on the icon.

```
$(this).parents('.f1').find('.f1-progress-line');

    fieldsetToActivate = $(this).data('step');
    let direction;
    if (current_active_step.data('step') > fieldsetToActivate) {
        direction = 'left';
    } else {
        direction = 'right';
    }
    $("form.f1 fieldset").hide();
    current_active_step.removeClass('active');
    // bar_progress(progress_line, direction);
    // ************* //
    var number_of_steps = progress_line.data('number-of-steps');
    var now_value = progress_line.data('now-value');

    var new_value = 0;
    if (direction == 'right') {
        new_value = fieldsetToActivate * (100 / number_of_steps);
    } else if (direction == 'left') {
        new_value = fieldsetToActivate * (100 / number_of_steps);
    }
    console.log('now:' + now_value + '- new: ' + new_value);
    progress_line.attr('style', 'width: ' + new_value + '%;').data('now-value', new_value);
    // ****************** //
    $('.f1').find(`fieldset[data-step='${fieldsetToActivate}']`).fadeIn('slow');
    // change icons
    $('.f1-step').removeClass('activated');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    for (let j = 0; j < fieldsetToActivate; j++) {
        $('.f1').find(`.f1-step[data-step='${j}']`).addClass('activated');
    }
});
```

This is not the best solution, but this will get your job done

Comment: Could you please check this fiddle? : https://jsfiddle.net/8uwn0ph0/4/ The same code however doesn't seem to work if i inculde form content within this template.

Comment: Thanks! It works great :) If I have to add a button on every step's page to navigate to a specific step ( say, "Go to Flows B" to go to Flows B), how to achieve this?

Comment: Fiddle updated. please check. You can place the button anywhere you want, i placed it on top for convenience.

Comment: Wow genius :) Thanks so much. Verified and up-voted :)

Comment: What about my question on [Using Step Wizard in Application Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57753630/using-step-wizard-in-application-form)? Thanks in advance...